# Decreasing returns to scale vs downward sloping demand curve

Tags: microeconomics

How can one show that decreasing returns + perfect competition is equivalent to monopolistic competition + constant returns?

Comment: 1. It is not; though some variables do have the same equilibrium values. Please provide context/source for your claim, otherwise it is hard to tell what exactly you are asking.

Comment: 2. Your title includes "*downward sloping demand curve*", but then it does not come up in the body of your question; please edit to clarify.

Comment: Downward sloping demand curve is implied by monopolistic competition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple case to show these two are isomorphic in terms of the firm problem.

**Perfect Competition:**

Each firm $i$ produces a homogeneous good with a decreasing returns to scale production technology $f(i) =  (s(i) n(i))^{\theta}$, where $s$ is productivity, $n$ is the only input labor, and $\theta<1$. Each firm maximizes their static profit $\max_{n_i} pf(s_i, n_i)-wn_i$ and use $n_i^*(s_i,p,w)$ labor.

**Monopolistic Competition with Constant Return:**

Each firm $i$ produces a differentiated good with linear production function, $f(i)=s(i) n(i)$. Assume representative agent has preferences over different goods $U=\left(\int c(i)^{\theta} d i\right)^{1 / \theta}$. (Alternatively assume a final good produced by perfectly competitive firms with the production function of this.)

From the utility maximization problem we obtain $U^{1-\theta} c(i)^{\theta-1}=\lambda p(i)$ , where $\lambda$ is the multiplier of consumer's budget constraint (or $\lambda^{-1}$ is the aggregate price index).
Each firm's revenue is thus $p(i) c(i)=U^{1-\theta} \lambda^{-1} c(i)^{\theta}= U^{1-\theta} \lambda^{-1}(s(i) n(i))^{\theta}$ where we assume the agent has measure of 1 and thus $c(i)=f(i)$. Each firm thus maximize $\max_{n_i} p(s(i) n(i))^{\theta}-wn(i)$ where $p \equiv  U^{1-\theta} \lambda^{-1}$ and use $n_i^*(s_i,p,w)$ labor.

**In summary**, both decreasing return to scale and monopolistic competition provide some curvature  in firm objective function to pin down the firm size.

Comment: I would not call the two cases "isomorphic". Yes, the firms' optimization problem is identical given a specific functional forms and a parameter $\theta$ that is used in different aspects of the models but just happens to coincide, but I don't see how this is "isomorphic".

Comment: Perfect thanks!